# Resize a window at 1 px emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, dot-emacs

I have managed to resize a window so that it is 3 characters wide but I need to make it 0 but still be able to edit it

[image: current situation]

Current code:
 `(window-resize nil (- (truncate (* 0.06 (frame-width))) (window-width)) t)`

Comment: What are you trying to do ? If all you want is to have a "floating frame" used to show the scratch buffer, you don't need to have a window showing it on the side - and so you don't need to resize it to 0px to hide it, as you can *not* show it in the first place. But may be I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Numbra You could not focus on a posframe buffer so I had to have the real one to edit, I solved the issue now by change ```show-posframe```

Comment: I think you can. `posframe-show` has an `:accept-focus` key parameter, and any modification made in this frame will actually be a modification of the underlying buffer.